# Rxjs toPromise behavior different than observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a simple example where two methods create and return a promise. The second method `buildRedCar()` calls the first method `buildCar()`, modifies the value returned by the promise and returns another promise from itself. The code then calls `buildRedCar()`, and just console.logs the result out. This does not work when converting to promises, but it *does* work when using straight observables.

Does **not** work:

```
import * as Rx from 'rx';

function buildCar(): Rx.IPromise<string> {
    let car = 'Car';
    return Rx.Observable.just<string>(car).toPromise();
}

function buildRedCar(): Rx.IPromise<string> {
    let observable = Rx.Observable.create<string>((observer) => {
        buildCar().then((car) => {
            observer.onNext('Red ' + car);
        });
    })

    return observable.toPromise();
}

buildRedCar().then((car) => {
    console.log(car);
});
```

**Does** work:

```
import * as Rx from 'rx';

function buildCar(): Rx.Observable<string> {
    let car = 'Car';
    return Rx.Observable.just<string>(car);
}

function buildRedCar(): Rx.Observable<string> {
    let observable = Rx.Observable.create<string>((observer) => {
        buildCar().subscribe((car) => {
            observer.onNext('Red ' + car);
        });
    })

    return observable;
}

buildRedCar().subscribe((car) => {
    console.log(car);
});
```

Any idea why the different behavior when the only difference is converting the observable to a promise before returning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When RxJs converts an Observable to a Promise, it creates a Promise that will yield the *last* value from the observable.  Thus the promise will not resolve until the underlying observable completes.

In your first example (and in your second as well), you never complete the red car observable.  Therefore the promise never resolves.  Therefore the observable that wraps the promise never produces a value...

Your 2nd example works because the subscription eagerly prints the first value produced by your red car observable as it arrives, and then "waits" for further results that never arrive.

Adding a call to `onComplete` should make your first version work:

```
observer.onNext('Red ' + car);
observer.onComplete();
```