# Can you return an observable as a promise in Angular 2 (Using Typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am learning to develop in Ionic 2 using Angular 2 and Typescript.

What I am immediately trying to is create a function that returns a promise that gets resolved when an observed variable changes.

This would be useful for me to detect when initialisation within a provider has been completed before page components attempt to use it. e.g.

```
api.isInitialized()
    .then(() => {
        //api provider is initialized. Now safe to call it!
        return api.fetch("NEWS");
    });
    .then((newsData) => {
        //do something with newsData
    });
```

I have the following imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Just to check my understanding of how toPromise would work I tried calling the following function. I only get "testObservable has changed". 
I was hoping to also get "promise resolved".

How would I get a change to testObservable to result in a resolved promise?

```
 observerTest(){
    let testObservable: any;
    let testObserver: any;

    testObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
        testObserver = observer;
    });

    let myPromise = testObservable.toPromise();

    testObservable.subscribe(data => {
        console.log("testObservable has changed.");
        console.log(data);
    });

    myPromise.then(() =>{
        console.log("promise resolved.");
    });

    testObserver.next(true);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because you have choose between resolving your observable as an observable with the `.subscribe` or as a promise with the `toPromise().then`
If you do both only one will be called once resolved.

Comment: I found that replacing the last line with testObserver.complete(); gives me the behaviour I wanted.  As mentioned by Brandon in response to question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557214/rxjs-topromise-behavior-different-than-observable ) "When RxJs converts an Observable to a Promise, it creates a Promise that will yield the last value from the observable. Thus the promise will not resolve until the underlying observable completes."

Answer (score 9):

The official [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) contains examples, especially in the [HTTP chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). For example:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and

```
delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => null)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can return an Observable as a promise. Assuming `api.fetch("NEWS")` returns an Observable.

```
test(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        api.fetch("NEWS")
        .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        },(err) => {
            resolve(err);
        });
    });
}
```

And at calling side you will handle it as promise:

```
provider.test().then(data => {
    console.log("Data : ",data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error : ",err);
});
```

Though, I am not sure, why you want to return an Observable as a promise?

1 use case might be - there are already a lot of calling methods which are written to receive a promise from a provider. Now, suddenly a provider code returns an Observable than a Promise.

Otherwise, it is just simpler to handle Observable via `.subscribe()` and Promise via `.then()` from calling method.

Comment: `resolve(err)` should be `reject(err)`, right?